# Using a list of matrix names

Tags: r

I have 75 matrices that I want to search through. The matrices are named a1r1, a1r2, a1r3, a1r4, a1r5, a2r1,...a15r5, and I have a list with all 75 of those names in it; each matrix has the same number of rows and columns. Inside some nested for loops, I also have a line of code that, for the first matrix looks like this:

```
total <- (a1r1[row,i]) + (a1r1[row,j]) + (a1r1[row,k])
```

(i, j, k, and row are all variables that I am looping over.) I would like to automate this line so that the for loops would fully execute using the first matrix in the list, then fully execute using the second matrix and so on. How can I do this?

(I'm an experienced programmer, but new to R, so I'm willing to be told I shouldn't use a list of the matrix names, etc. I realize too that there's probably a better way in R than for loops, but I was hoping for sort of quick and dirty at my current level of R expertise.)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why not put the matrices themselves in a list?

Answer (score 3):

Here The R way to do this :

```
lapply(ls(pattern='a[0-9]r[0-9]'),
       function(nn) {
         x <- get(nn)
         sum(x[row,c(i,j,k)])
       })
```

1. `ls` will give a list of variable having a certain pattern name
2. You loop through the resulted list using `lapply`
3. `get` will transform the name to a varaible
4. use multi indexing with the vectorized `sum`  function

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice to build automatically lists of names designating your objects. You can build such lists with `paste`, `rep`, and sequences as `0:10`, etc. Once you have a list of object names (let's call it `mylist`), the `get` function applied on it gives the objects themselves.